# Tomcat 7/ Windows - How to redirect output to a file but keep the original output in the console

Tags: tomcat, windows-8.1

I redirect the Tomcat 7 output to a file by applying these parameters to catalina.bat

`catalina.bat run > ..\logs\tomcat.log 2>&1`

However I don't want to lose the standard output, I want to keep it, so it will still appear in either Eclipse Console or in the command line window. How can I archive that?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell has a [tee](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) command, you could try something like this.

`catalina.bat run 2>&1 | tee ..\logs\tomcat.log`